# Can the value at the address pointed by a pointer be assigned to the address pointed by another pointer? And how can i solve this min-max problem in C

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, function-pointers

I have two questions.

**MY CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arrayFonk(int *dizi, int size, int *minimum, int *maximum){
    int i;
    int b;
    
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if(*(dizi + i) > *(dizi + i + 1)){
            b = *(dizi + i);
            
            /* *minimum = *(dizi + i + 1); */
            
        } else {
            b = *(dizi + i + 1);
            
            /**minimum = *(dizi + i);*/
        }
    }
    
    *maximum = b;
    
    int j;
    int c;
    
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++){
        if(*(dizi + j) < *(dizi + j + 1)){
            /* *minimum = *(dizi + j);*/ 
            c = *(dizi + j);
        } else {
            /* *minimum = *(dizi + j + 1);*/
            c = *(dizi + j + 1);
        }
    }
    
    *minimum = c;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    
    int min, max;
    
    arrayFonk(&a[0], 5, &min, &max);
    
    printf("En büyük değer: %d\n", max);
    
    printf("En küçük değer: %d\n", min);

    return 0;
}
```

First: With this code, I want to find the **largest** and *smallest* elements in the array and print them on the screen. The program finds the largest element *correctly* and prints it, but when I want to find the smallest element, it gives me a *constant value* of **0** in everytime (even if I change the loop variable, the result remains the same). How can I solve this problem?

Second: For example; `*minimum = *(array + i);`
Can the value at the address pointed by a pointer be assigned to the value at the address pointed by another pointer, as in this example (with correctly defined pointers)? If this is possible, is this example correct (in terms of writing syntax and working)?

As another way to find the smallest element in the array, I tried assigning it to another variable, *just like I did for the largest element*, and then assigning it to the `min` variable in the main function with the `*minimum` pointer in my function, but the result remained 0 again. I'm waiting to learn how to solve this problem and get a clear answer to my second question.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: If `size` is the number of elements of `dizi`, then `*(dizi + i + 1)` will go out of bounds in the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't do `*(dizi + i + 1)`, do `dizi[i + 1]`

Comment: Also note that for any pointer (or array) `dizi` and index `i`, the expression `*(dizi + i)` is *exactly* equal to `dizi[i]`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo why? this is a pointer. how the pointer has a index?

Comment: Yes and as @Someprogrammerdude mentioned: the expressions are exactly equal.  If it helps, instead of declaring `int *dizi` in the parameter list, make it `int dizi[]`. I usually use `int *dizi` if the parameter is a pointer to a single element and `int dizi[]` if it's a pointer to the first of multiple elements.

Comment: Btw, are you using gcc or clang? If so, compile with `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined` and then run the program. It will provide you with very good information in this case. With gcc, you can add `-fanalyzer` too which will point you at a possible problem with `b` being used while uninitialized.

Answer (score 3):

1. You overcomplicate it.

   ```
   void arrayFonk(int *dizi, size_t size, int *minimum, int *maximum)
   {
       if(dizi && size)
       {
           *maximum = dizi[0];    
           *minimum = dizi[0];    
           for(size_t i = 1; i < size; i++)
           {
               if(dizi[i] > *maximum) *maximum = dizi[i];
               else if(dizi[i] < *minimum) *minimum = dizi[i];
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. You access the array outside it bounds (`*(dizi + i + 1))`) - thus it does not work. I would suggest using the array index notation as it is easier to read (the compiler does not care)
3. `array[i] === *(array + i)`

Comment: I'd probably store the minimum and maximum values in local variables to save between 2 and 4 dereferences each iteration.

Comment: @IanAbbott it was for the sake of simplicity

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
*minimum = *(dizi + i + 1);
```

is syntactically valid, but algorithmically wrong, because of your `i < size` criteria, which makes sure that the last value of `i` will be `size - 1`. Now, interpositioning it, we know that the last value of `*(dizi + i + 1)` will be equivalent to `*(dizi + size)`. Since C is a 0-indexed language, that is, the first index is 0, if you have `size` elements, then the last index is `size - 1`, so you will need

```
*minimum = *(dizi + i);
```

instead. Let's simplify and fix your code:

```
void arrayFonk(int *dizi, int size, int *minimum, int *maximum){
    if ((size <= 0) || !dizi) {
        return; //invalid input
    }
    //We initialize minimum and maximum by the first value
    //and we will override them if we need to
    *minimum = *maximum = *dizi;
    //We start the loop from 1 because we already handled the 0'th item
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        //For each item we override minimum if we found a lesser
        //value and maximum if we found a greater value
        if (*minimum > *(dizi + i)) *minimum = *(dizi + i);
        else if (*maximum < *(dizi + i)) *maximum = *(dizi + i);
    }
}
```

Notice that I have used your `*(dizi + i)` notation instead of `dizi[i]` to adhere to your coding style, but for me it's more intuitive to use square brackets instead.

Comment: I would suggest using the correct type for sizes. `int` is not the correct one

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem with simple touch.

```
`#include <stdio.h>

void arrayFonk(int *dizi, int size, int *minimum, int *maximum){
    int i;
    int b;
    
    *minimum = *dizi;
    *maximum = *minimum;
    
    for(i = 1; i < size; i++){
        if(*(dizi + i - 1) > *(dizi + i)){
            b = *(dizi + i - 1);
            
            /* *minimum = *(dizi + i + 1); */
        }
    }
    
    *maximum = b;
    
    int j;
    int c;
    
    for(j = 1; j < size; j++){
        if(*(dizi + j - 1) > *(dizi + j)){
            /* *minimum = *(dizi + j);*/ 
            c = *(dizi + j);
        }
        
        if(*dizi < c){
            c = *dizi;
        }
    }
    
    *minimum = c;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 6, 5}; /*sayilari degistir tekrar dene*/ 
    
    int min, max; /*yerel değişkenler*/
    
    arrayFonk(&a[0], 5, &min, &max);
    
    printf("En büyük değer: %d\n", max);
    
    printf("En küçük değer: %d\n", min);

    return 0;
}`
```

it is working like i want in a seperate file but not working with in a crowd C file like this:

```
`#include <stdio.h>

void uzunluk();

void arrayFonk(int *dizi, int size, int *minimum, int *maximum){
    int i;
    int b;
    
    *minimum = *dizi;
    *maximum = *minimum;
    
    for(i = 1; i < size; i++){
        if(*(dizi + i - 1) > *(dizi + i)){
            b = *(dizi + i - 1);
            
            /* *minimum = *(dizi + i + 1); */
        }
    }
    
    *maximum = b;
    
    int j;
    int c;
    
    for(j = 1; j < size; j++){
        if(*(dizi + j - 1) > *(dizi + j)){
            /* *minimum = *(dizi + j);*/ 
            c = *(dizi + j);
        }
        
        if(*dizi < c){
            c = *dizi;
        }
    }
    
    *minimum = c;
}


struct fatura{
    char urunadi[50];
    float fiyat;
    int miktar;
};


int main()
{
    uzunluk(7);
    
    printf("\n");
    
    /*Soru 2 (8)*/
    
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; /*sayilari degistir tekrar dene*/ 
    
    int min, max; /*yerel değişkenler*/
    
    arrayFonk(&a[0], 5, &min, &max);
    
    printf("En büyük değer: %d\n", max);
    
    printf("En küçük değer: %d\n", min);
    
    /*Soru 3 (7)*/
    
    struct fatura Urunler[50]; /*struct fatura tipinde bir dizi*/
    
    int j;
    
    for(j = 0; j < 50; j++){
        printf("%d. Ürünün adınıgir: \n", j+1);
        scanf("%s", Urunler[j].urunadi);
        printf("%d. Ürünün fiyatını gir: \n", j+1);
        scanf("%f", &Urunler[j].fiyat);
        printf("%d. Ürünün adını, fiyatını ve miktarını gir: \n", j+1);
        scanf("%d", &Urunler[j].miktar);
    }
    
    float toplam;
    /*
    for(j = 0; j < 50; j++){
        toplam
    }
    */
    
    return 0;
}

/*Soru 1 (10 Numaralı)*/
void uzunluk(int input){
    if(input < 10) {
        int i = 1;
        for(i; i <= input; i++){
            printf("%d", i);
        }
    } else {
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < input; j++){
            printf("8");
        }
    }
}`
```

can you tell me where is the problem?